# Bind error message on another attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, simple-form

I have the following validation rule in a model

```
validates :csv_fingerprint, uniqueness: { message: "CSV was already uploaded." }
```

In the form view (simple_form), the following code generates the file upload field:

```
= f.input :csv, as: :file
```

The validation works, but the error message is not shown at the upload field. I think, the reason is, that the validation is for *:csv_fingerprint* and the form field is *:csv*.

How can I tell the validation rule, that the message should be displayed at the *:csv* field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `f.error`:

```
= f.input :csv, as: :file
= f.error :csv_fingerprint
```

Also you can check errors for attribute like this:

```
errors_for(@model, :attribute)
```

You can then iterate over these and display them.

Yet another way to get object's errors: `@model.errors.on(:attribute)`

Comment: Thanks. So there's no option in the validator to specify a message-attribute. You have to go in the view.

Comment: @Christian is this a question? Because I am not sure whether I can answer it in anyway :)

Comment: @Christian model's validators usually operate on, roughly speaking, on database columns. And responsibility of the way you display validation errors lays on the view layer.

Comment: You're right. But the view (Twitter Bootstrap) get's quite complicated, if you want to display the error message and the file upload field in red, if there's an error for :csv_fingerprint.
Another option would be a custom validation method, because you can set the error to a specific field: *errors.add(:csv, "already uploaded")*